# delete 6 month back log streams of all CloudWatch log groups in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I need to delete the log streams which are more than 6 months of all the log groups in CloudWatch. We have thousands of log groups, deleting one by one is a time taking process. Is there a way to delete the log streams as a bulk?

Comment: Why not just change the retention period of the log groups, and let Amazon delete them for you?

Comment: @MarkB - unless they've changed the behavior within the past month, setting a retention period deletes the messages but not the streams. Which means that if you do a `DescribeLogStreams` or anything similar you'll go through page after page of empty streams (with a relatively low throttling rate).

Comment: @Bhargav - you can use/adapt the code here: https://github.com/kdgregory/aws-misc/tree/trunk/lambda/cloudwatch-log-cleanup

Comment: Great Thanks to all for spending time on this. I followed the github link which provided above. Script is working as expected. its resolved now.